# Is Xcode 6.0.1 copying bundle resource into the wrong folder?

Tags: file, bundle, xcode6, relative-path

I've created a commandline Xcode project.

```
PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "/Users/pi/Desktop/test_simple.py")
```

^ that works, but I want to have test_simple.py in my project tree.

Here's how I fixed it:

[image]

Then from the command line:

```
> find /Users/pi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ -iname "test_simple.py"
/Users/pi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
    /test_PyCXX-ewhsclbqmuqouofppbnxmqrnojrv/Build/Products/Debug
    /usr/share/man/man1/test_simple.py
```

Compare this against the path the executable gets created at:

```
/Users/pi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
     /test_PyCXX-ewhsclbqmuqouofppbnxmqrnojrv/Build/Products/Debug
```

And then adapt the code:

```
PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "./usr/share/man/man1/test_simple.py");
```

Ok, that works. But what is going on with /usr/share/man/man1/ ?  That is what the 'subpath' field in the screenshot originally contained.  I deleted it and replaced it with './py'.

Then I cleaned and rebuilt my project.

I should be able to run:

```
PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "./py/test_simple.py");
```

I think...?

So why did subpath contain that weird original value? And why does it insist on using this value even when I tell it to use something else?

Have I found a small bug here? Maybe it is failing to parse './py' and falling back on this default.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that it is indeed putting everything in a ./py/ folder as it should be.

I think there is a minor bug in that cleaning the project fails to remove the file from the other location.

i.e. I must've done a build using the default location.